# Javascript - Check if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have trying to see if a cookie exists or not, Here is my getCookie method:

```
function getCookie(name)
    {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    }
```

and here is how I calling that method:

```
var cookie = getCookie("counter");
```

and here is my condition I tried:

```
if(cookie == '')
        {
        }
        else
        {
             //Always goes here even when I clear my cookies and I know it does not exist.
        }
```

My condition always goes into the else, not matter what, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cookie` will be set to `undefined` - not a blank string. Try `if (cookie)` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the value of cookie if not undefined

```
    if (typeof(cookie)  === 'undefined'){
     CONSOLE.LOG('no cookie');
    } else {
     CONSOLE.LOG(' cookie exist');
    }
```

Comment: how would I do the opposite? typeof(cookie) !== 'undefined') ?

Comment: just modify the statement to `if (!!cookie)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try following function to get cookie:

```
    function getCookie(c_name){
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1){
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1){
      c_value = null;
    }
    else {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1)
      {
    c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
    }
```